# php multidimensional array group number of occurrences by type and date

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-07-18
        [1] => 22 SSH
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-07-18
        [1] => 80 HTTP
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-07-18
        [1] => 3389 Remote Desktop
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-07-19
        [1] => 3389 Remote Desktop
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-07-19
        [1] => 3389 Remote Desktop
    )
)
```

and need the data counted by day and number of occurrences in the following format:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=> "3389 Remote Desktop"
    [1]=> "1,2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=> "22 SSH"
    [1]=> "1,0"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=> "80 HTTP"
    [1]=> "1,0"
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this? I am able to count all occurences but not grouped by date and type like this:

```
$counts = array();
foreach( $stack_stats_timeline as $value) {
    foreach( $value as $k => $v) {
        if( !isset( $counts[$k])) $counts[$k] = array();
        if( !isset( $counts[$k][$v])) $counts[$k][$v] = 0;
        $counts[$k][$v] += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: where does the source array come from? If it came out of the database then you should write an other query.

Comment: I generate it with PHP myself. Please give me a solution with an other source array if possible. I can adjust the source array if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this'll help you to get it work

```
$result = array();
$count = 1;
foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {
    $hash = $value[1];
    $result[$hash][0] = $value[1];
    $result[$hash][1][$value[0]] = (isset($result[$hash][1][$value[0]])) ? $count + 1 : $count;
}
print_r(array_values($result));
```

Comment: that works great! I run however in an other problem now: when the array keys of each occurence is the date it does not work for my purposes. How can I reset the array keys to default after I sorted them by date?

Comment: Just set your `$hash` into `$value[0]` and that's it